# Is the statue used in Darkwing Duck of The Great Mouse Detective?

Tags: reference, darkwing-duck

In the *Darkwing Duck* episode "Duck Blind" we see the statue used by DW to take him to his lair.  Is this of The Great Mouse Detective?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as mentioned in [Darkwing Fandom](https://darkwingduck.fandom.com/wiki/Darkwing%27s_chair_set), the statuette that helps spin the chair is indeed of The Great Mouse Detective. It has been confirmed by Tad Stones, the program creator himself as follows:

> Tad Stones has explained this reference as follows:"I shared an
> office with Ron Clements. Ron loved Sherlock Holmes and went on with
> John Musker and Burny Mattinsonto do The Great Mouse Detective. I
> wanted to put a nod towards my friends in features in there; why not
> Basil? We never talked about it, I just did it. It was more of Hey,
> here's a detective, and Ron's a friend of mine, why not?".

Comment: All these childhood memories popping up... :)